# Is there some way to use .bind or .apply to give a called method the scope of the calling method or loop?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, scope, bind, apply

```
function foo(itemA) {
  async.waterfall(
    [
      function(callback) {
        console.log("I can see itemA as " + itemA); // <-- this works fine
        callback(null);
      },
      outerFunction // <-- this method doesn't have access to itemA
    ],
    function(err, item) {}
  );
}

function outerFunction(callback) {
  //item A is not defined so this barfs
  console.log("I'm going to throw an exception cause... " + itemA);
}
```

For the sake of neatness I neither want to define all my functions inside the waterfall, nor do I want to play all sorts of elaborate games passing around some object that contains the values so that these methods have access to them, but I'm not clear on how (or if) it's possible to use `bind` or `apply` to give these externally defined methods access to `itemA` or if there's some other mechanism that I'm not familiar with that would make this possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Scope in Javascript is lexical (based on the position of the code).  You cannot change the scope of a function that is already declared.

You can however simply pass `itemA` to `outerFunction` as an argument when you call it.  That is the usual and expected way to solve a problem like this.

There are other techniques for giving things more automatic access to a set of variables like assigning a value to a higher, but shared scope or making things methods on a common object that all can share access to instance data, but it is not obvious from your description of the issue whether either of these is appropriate in this case.

> but I'm not clear on how (or if) it's possible to use bind or apply to
>   give these externally defined methods access to itemA or if there's
>   some other mechanism that I'm not familiar with that would make this
>   possible.

`.bind()` and `.apply()` do not affect scope in any way.  They give you control over the value of `this` and/or arguments to the function.  If the variable of interest was available on some object, then you could use `.bind()`, `.apply()` or `.call()` to set the value of `this` to that object and allow your function to access the data via `this.property`.

Comment: I had a feeling that's the case, but was hoping I was overlooking some way to do this.  As my question states, I'm clear on how to pass the values in and use them, as I've been doing for years... it just dawned on me that perhaps I've been overlooking a really powerful mechanism, but alas, it would appear I haven't been.

Comment: @GeniaS. - Not via scope.  Scope in Javascript is based on the lexical layout of the code - not something you can modify with `.bind()` or `.apply()`.

Comment: "*Scope in Javascript is lexical…*" except for [*with*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-with-statement), but no one mentions that any more. ;-)

Comment: @RobG - Oh yeah, that abomination called `with` that nobody uses.  For very good reason, it's prohibited in strict mode and not recommended to be used because of ambiguity issues and it gets in the way of interpreter optimizations.  Even still, I don't think it does what the OP is asking for anyway because you pass an object to `with` - you can't take the current function's scope and suddenly make it available inside another function.